# Get Property Value Intersection of two objects in an ontology using OWL API

Tags: java, owl, ontology, owl-api

I am new to OWL API and trying to experiment with it. I have created a simple ontology in protege and reciprocal application in eclipse using OWL API. Ontology structure is as follows:-

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 Class                Object       (Data Property)StringValue  ObjectProperty relatedTo    
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
 WordString             WS1                    "One"                   DS1
                        WS2                    "Two"                   DS2
                        WS3                    "Three"                 DS3

 DigiString             DS1                    "1"  
                        DS2                    "2"  
                        DS3                    "3"  
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Complete ontology is as follows:-

```
<rdf:RDF xmlns="http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#"
 xml:base="http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl"
 xmlns:DigiWord="http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#"
 xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#"
 xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
 xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#"
 xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
<owl:Ontology rdf:about="http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl"/>
<!-- 
// Object Properties
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#relatedTo -->
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="&DigiWord;relatedTo">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
</owl:ObjectProperty>
<!-- 
//
// Data properties
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#stringValue -->

<owl:DatatypeProperty rdf:about="&DigiWord;stringValue">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="&xsd;string"/>
</owl:DatatypeProperty>
<!-- 
// Classes
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#DigiString -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#WordString -->
<owl:Class rdf:about="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
<!-- 
// Individuals
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 -->
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#DS1 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;DS1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">1</stringValue>
    <relatedTo rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WS1"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#DS2 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;DS2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">2</stringValue>
    <relatedTo rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WS2"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#DS3 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;DS3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;DigiString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string"></stringValue>
    <relatedTo rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WS3"/>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#WS1 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;WS1">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">One</stringValue>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#WS2 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;WS2">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Two</stringValue>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
<!-- http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#WS3 -->
<owl:NamedIndividual rdf:about="&DigiWord;WS3">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&DigiWord;WordString"/>
    <stringValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;string">Three</stringValue>
</owl:NamedIndividual>
</rdf:RDF>
```

I want to retrieve Object WS1 for DS1, WS2 for DS2 i.e upon providing strings "1", "2" etc my code should retrieve "One" , "Two" respectively. I have not come across any relevant code of this type on net.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not very clear what your ontology looks like. Can you just add the axioms in Manchester or Functional syntax?

Comment: @mikrohelen Sir i haved placed complete ontology. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example (OWLAPI 4) should help:

```
    OWLOntology o = ... your ontology here
    String ns = "http://localhost:3030/DigiWord.owl#";
    OWLDataFactory df = o.getOWLOntologyManager().getOWLDataFactory();
    OWLObjectProperty relatedto = df.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create(ns + "relatedTo"));
    OWLDataProperty stringValue = df.getOWLDataProperty(IRI.create(ns + "stringValue"));
    SimpleRenderer renderer = new SimpleRenderer();
    for (OWLNamedIndividual i : o.getIndividualsInSignature()) {
        for (OWLLiteral lit : EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(i, stringValue, o)) {
            System.out.println(i + " has values " + renderer.render(lit));
        }
        for (OWLIndividual related : EntitySearcher.getObjectPropertyValues(i, relatedto, o)) {
            for (OWLLiteral lit : EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(related, stringValue, o)) {
                System.out.println(i + " related to " + related + " which has values " + renderer.render(lit));
            }
        }
    }
```

Edit: to find matches for your query:

```
    for (OWLNamedIndividual i : o.getIndividualsInSignature()) {
        for (OWLIndividual related : EntitySearcher.getObjectPropertyValues(i, relatedto, o)) {
            for (OWLLiteral lit : EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(related, stringValue, o)) {
                if(lit.getLexicalForm().equals("1")){
                    for (OWLLiteral lit : EntitySearcher.getDataPropertyValues(i, stringValue, o)) {
                        System.out.println(i + " has values " + renderer.render(lit));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This prints every thing. My problem to access individual classes. eg if i input "1" from console. the application should print "one". That means DS1 is first accessed as its string value is 1, then WS1 is retrieved as DS1 is relatedTo WS1 and finally "one" would be printed. Please help with this as there is no luck with documentation and google. Thanks a million.

Comment: what you need is to match the value of a literal to an individual. By this I mean that you need to find `i`, in my example, where lit has lexical form "1", nd get the other values for stringValue for that individual